# XML Conditional Validation based on Primary Key

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, conditional-statements, schema

- Input for create Person (If PersonID don't exist then it is the input for creating new person, so input should contain other other four.)

  `<Input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Person>
      <FirstName>First Name</FirstName>
      <LastName>Last Name</LastName>
      <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
      <Email>username@domain.com</Email>
    </Person>
  </Input>`
- Input for update Person (If it has PersonID, then that will be the input for an update and input should contain at least one from other four along with PersonID.)

  `<Input xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Person>
      <PersonID>123456</PersonID>
      <FirstName>First Name</FirstName>
      <LastName>Last Name</LastName>
      <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
      <Email>username@domain.com</Email>
    </Person>
  </Input>`

**How to write single XSD to validate the input based on the PersonID?**

Thanks.

Comment: You can't express your constraint in XSD 1.0, but see the duplicate link for how you could use `xs:assert` to express it in XSD 1.1.